# Fetch properties from Sonarqube via Sonarqube wsClient

Tags: sonarqube

I'd like to fetch `sonar.timemachine.period1` via wsclient.
Seeing that it doesn't have one, I decided to bake one for myself

```
private Map<String, String> retrievePeriodProperties(final WsClient wsClient, int requestedPeriod) {
    if (requestedPeriod > 0) {
        final WsRequest propertiesWsRequestPeriod =
                new GetRequest("api/properties/sonar.timemachine.period" + requestedPeriod);
        final WsResponse propertiesWsResponsePeriod =
                wsClient.wsConnector().call(propertiesWsRequestPeriod);
        if (propertiesWsResponsePeriod.isSuccessful()) {
            String resp = propertiesWsResponsePeriod.content();
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(Integer.toString(requestedPeriod), resp);
            return map;
        }
    }
    return new HashMap<>();
}
```

but it always return an empty `Map<>`

Any lead where I can go from this direction?

Comment: what is the version of SonarQube?

Comment: hi @Teryk-SonarSource, I'm running LTS SonarQube. As stated below, I've successfully access them via `org.sonar.api.config.Settings `. I'll mark it as answer tomorrow. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `org.sonar.api.config.Settings` to fetch properties defined in SonarQube.